# What if the first card after an attack card is a kitten, does one need to draw a second card?

Tags: exploding-kittens

Which of the following two rules takes precedent?

1. After an attack card the next player draws 2 cards.
2. If an exploding kitten is drawn and the player can defuse it, the kitten goes back into the pile and the turn ends.

If an attack card is played, the next player draws a card, it's a kitten, player defuses it, kitten goes back into the pile, and now the attacked player needs to draw a second card or his/her turn ends?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The effect of the **Attack** card is as follows:

> End your turn without drawing a card. Force the next player to take two turns.

Therefore the next player has to draw again even if the first card is a kitten. Their turn ends by defusing it but then their second turn starts.